# Adding new headers and splitting column

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a large `csv` with data that I have imported to python with pandas.
The first 3 rows of the `csv` look like the following.

```
“PATIENT”,"MD",“REFMD”,“DIAGNOSIS_HISTORY”,“AVAILABLE_STUDIES”
“patient1\nPID1\npAge1”,“MDname1\nMDname3”,” RefDoctorName1”,“Prostate cancer”,”No Path\n CT ClinicName (CAP)  - 11/30/2015\n Nuclear: ClinicName (Bone Scan)  - 11/30/2015"
"patient2\nPID2\npAge2”,”MDname2\nSeen 10/12/2015”,“RefDoctorName2”,”Prostate cancer”,”Path: O/S - Prostate Bx 11/12/2014”
```

I want to

- split the first `column` in 3 parts from “PATIENT” to “PATIENT_Name”, "PID", "pAGE" and
- in the second column remove the second MD if there one and add a new column of "MD2" to collect those times when a patient saw more than one MD at the same clinic.
- Also, I want to split out the incidences of \nSeen Date in the MD column and place that in a new column titled "Date_Seen".

I have all the columns split out, but having a hard time with the next step.

```
import pandas as pd
f = pd.read_csv("/path/file.csv")
pat = f.iloc[0:,:1]
refmd = f.iloc[0:,2:3]
diag = f.iloc[0:,3:4]
```

Comment: See my answer below - it's missing the 'Seen DATE` part. Would this only occur for MD1, or could this apply to each `MD`?

Comment: Thanks. I will do that for sure.  This worked perfect.  I'm pretty new at all this so that was super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with the following:

```
df.columns = [re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9\\]+', '', c).strip() for c in df.columns]
for i, col in df.items():
    df.loc[:, i] = col.str.replace(r'[^A-Za-z0-9\\ ]+', '').str.strip()
```

to get:

```
                 PATIENT                      MD           REFMD  \
0  patient1\nPID1\npAge1        MDname1\nMDname3  RefDoctorName1   
1  patient2\nPID2\npAge2  MDname2\nSeen 10122015  RefDoctorName2   

  DIAGNOSISHISTORY                                   AVAILABLESTUDIES  
0  Prostate cancer  No Path\n CT ClinicName CAP   11302015\n Nucle...  
1  Prostate cancer                      Path OS  Prostate Bx 11122014
```

To `split` and `expand` into new `columns` on the `newline` characters:

```
pat = df.iloc[:, 0].str.split(r'\\n', expand=True)
pat.columns = ['PATIENT_name', 'PID', 'pAGE']

  PATIENT_name   PID   pAGE
0     patient1  PID1  pAge1
1     patient2  PID2  pAge2
```

and:

```
md = df.iloc[:, 1].str.split(r'\\n', expand=True)
md.columns = ['MD', 'MD2']

        MD            MD2
0  MDname1        MDname3
1  MDname2  Seen 10122015
```